# Spark 2.3.2 Scala search pattern

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I have only N (num rows in pattern) and two datasets with types:

```
root
 |-- ts_begin: long (nullable = true)
 |-- btype: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- disp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- log_co: double (nullable = true)
```

One of them too big (history data) and one has size=N (generally no more then 10 rows).

Example of data (history):

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|  ts_begin|btype|   disp| log_co|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|1535536647|    1|3.44E-4| 4.4E-4|
|1535536947|    1|1.16E-4| 4.0E-4|
|1535537250|   -1|1.03E-4|-2.0E-4|
|1535537550|    1|1.15E-4| 1.4E-4|
|1535537847|    1| 1.5E-4| 1.7E-4|
|1535538148|   -1|1.27E-4|-3.8E-4|
|1535538447|    1| 8.6E-5| 8.0E-5|
|1535538747|   -1|1.13E-4|-1.6E-4|
|1535539047|   -1| 6.6E-5|-4.0E-5|
|1535539347|   -1|1.75E-4|-2.5E-4|
|1535539649|   -1|1.76E-4|-5.2E-4|
```

Example of pattern:

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|  ts_begin|btype|   disp| log_co|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
|1635536601|    1|3.44E-4| 4.4E-4|
|1635536902|    1|1.16E-4| 4.0E-4|
|1635537203|   -1|1.03E-4|-2.0E-4|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
```

I want to make a pattern search with conditions like this:

```
  pattern.row.btype == hist.row.btype and
  pattern.row.disp between hist.row.disp*0.8 and hist.row.disp*1.2
```

for all rows from a pattern.

Both datasets sorted by ts_begin asc.

ts_begin values not compared.

As a result, I want to see something like this:

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+--------+
|  ts_begin|btype|   disp| log_co|comp_res|
+----------+-----+-------+-------+--------+
|1535536647|    1|3.44E-4| 4.4E-4|       0|
|1535536947|    1|1.16E-4| 4.0E-4|       0|
|1535537250|   -1|1.03E-4|-2.0E-4|       0|
|1535537550|    1|1.15E-4| 1.4E-4|       1|
|1535537847|    1| 1.5E-4| 1.7E-4|       0|
|1535538148|   -1|1.27E-4|-3.8E-4|       0|
|1535538447|    1| 8.6E-5| 8.0E-5|       0|
|1535538747|   -1|1.13E-4|-1.6E-4|       1|
|1535539047|   -1| 6.6E-5|-4.0E-5|       0|
|1535539347|   -1|1.75E-4|-2.5E-4|       0|
|1535539649|   -1|1.76E-4|-5.2E-4|       0|
```

Little bit more explanation, 1 in field comp_res means that seq of rows

```
    |1535537550|    1|1.15E-4| 1.4E-4|
    |1535537847|    1| 1.5E-4| 1.7E-4|
    |1535538148|   -1|1.27E-4|-3.8E-4|
```

"is equal" to pattern.

I was tring solve it with using

```
 val lb = listBars
    .withColumn("rn", row_number() over Window.orderBy(col("ts_begin").asc) )
    .withColumn("rn", floor(($"rn"-1)/nBuckets))
    .withColumn("rnk", row_number() over Window.partitionBy("rn").orderBy(col("ts_begin").asc) )
    .groupBy("rn")
    .pivot("rnk", 1 to nBuckets)
    .agg(
      sum("ts_begin").alias("ts_begin"),
      sum("btype").alias("btype"),
      sum("disp").alias("disp"),
      sum("log_co").alias("log_co")
    )
```

and then UDF with 2 Rows as input, like ...

```
  def udf_comp(p: Row) = udf(
    (r: Row) =>
    {
```

It's looks like that exists more elegant solution without pivoting.

I hope it's possible to use Window function with group by whole datset, order by ts_begin asc and with dataframe from current row and some next:

```
  val windowSpec = Window
    .orderBy(col("ts_begin").asc)
    .rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, nBuckets-1)
```

and with UDAF that recive and accumulate all rows from Window and Pattern Dataframe and in "evaluate" make comparison equidimensional dataframes.

Also may be there is solution with left join of pattern.

Can you suggest me something? thanks.

Comment: As usual, ask on "steckoverflow" and solution is borning. I think that it possible make left joins (For N=3 we make 3 left joins with generating 3 additional fields in hist dataset. Like - join only 1-st pattern row with each other on hist and producing field cr1 = 0,1 and next joins that produce cr2,cr3 Next step is accumulate crX in one filed CRF and the last step is search groups of rows in hist with CRF=1 with using Window from curr and plus). I will do it and post here.

Comment: if patterns number small (<10), them can be read into memory as collection (maybe, broadcasted), and used in UDF. UDF will return 1 if history record match patterns.

Comment: UDF get only one row from hist, but I need 3,4,5 rows. Maybe you mean UDAF?

Comment: looks like to "history" dataframe one column "comp_res" have to be added with 1/0 values, please confirm? This column can be added with UDF: df.withColumn("comp_res",myUDF($"btype", ...)). UDF will contain collection from "pattern" dataframe, and just filter incoming parameters by "pattern" collection.

Comment: please confirm? Yes you rigth

Comment: "filter incoming parameters by "pattern" collection" yes, but incoming parameters can be only one row, otherwise I can use only UDAF and this can't take pattern as additional parameter as far as I know.

Comment: My be someone know? can I use table "t_barsPattern" created like this 
 barsPattern.createOrReplaceTempView("t_barsPattern") inside UDAF code?